# How to enable disable buttons in datalist

Tags: asp.net, database, datalist

I have got a datalist with some databound fields with 2 buttons. I want to enable disable button depending on the column(state) value of each row, so for instance if the value of state is 0 , the remove button should be disable and add button should be enabled similarly when the value of state is 1 , vice versa..

```
protected void dlEditCaravans_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    Button addtoFeauture = e.Item.FindControl("btnAddToFeature") as Button;
    Button removetoFeauture = e.Item.FindControl("btnRemoveFeature") as Button;
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(dlEditCaravans.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex]);
    int check = caravans.GetfeautureValue(id);

    if (check == 0)
    {
        addtoFeauture.Enabled = true;

    }

    else
    {
        removetoFeauture.Enabled = true;

    }

  }
```

I have tried something like above but it gives object reference not set to an instance error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ItemDatabound event of Datalist

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
 if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row;
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(dr["StateColumnName"])
        {
          ((Button)e.Item.FindControl("Button1")).Enable = True;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok let me try just for curiousity what does if ( e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem ) means

Comment: As there are different item template, like header, footer, item, alternate etc. but your button will item/alternate template and you want to enable/disable those instead header/footer template.

Comment: i m still confused , ur solutions works but i couldnt understand the logic , so u mean that we use e.item.itetype, to determine it is button or image , is that what you mean

Comment: Datalist could not find control in header, footer templates

Answer (score 1):

```
  void DataListProduct_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs e)
     {
         if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
             e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
         {

             Button BT = e.Item.FindControl(“ButtonID“) as Button;
             BT.Enable = True or false depends upon your condition
         }

     }
```

Comment: try to apply the condition if ( e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
             e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem )  also check null before using the button properties

Comment: ok let me try just for curiousity what does if ( e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem ) means